# AngularJS and Django

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django, forms

new to both django and AngularJs especially.

I have my data coming in from an SQL database into a table and i want to be able to sort and search it.

Basic Django model and view, i think it would be the html and js that i'm stuck with.

The data displays in the text with not issues, just the search and sort don't work.

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="box" ng-app="sortApp" ng-controller="mainController">

    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div>

                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search table" ng-model="searchTable">

            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'name'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
                        Name
                        <span ng-show="sortType == 'name' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
                        <span ng-show="sortType == 'name' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
                      </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'cost'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
                      Cost
                        <span ng-show="sortType == 'cost' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
                        <span ng-show="sortType == 'cost' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
                      </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'resource_type'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
                      Resource Type
                        <span ng-show="sortType == 'resource_type' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
                        <span ng-show="sortType == 'resource_type' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
                      </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'unit'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
                      Unit
                        <span ng-show="sortType == 'unit' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
                        <span ng-show="sortType == 'unit' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
                      </a>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </thead>

        <tbody>
            {% for resource in resource_list %}
            <tr ng-repeat="resource in resource_list | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:searchTable">
                <td>{{ resource.resource_name }}</td>
                <td>{{ resource.resource_cost }}</td>
                <td>{{ resource.resource_type }}</td>
                <td>{{ resource.resource_unit }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor resource%}

        </tbody>

    </table>
</div>
```

JS:

```
    // Resource Table
angular.module('sortApp', [])

.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
  $scope.sortType     = 'name'; // set the default sort type
  $scope.sortReverse  = false;  // set the default sort order
  $scope.searchTable   = '';     // set the default search/filter term

});
```

I think it might have something to do with this line `<tr ng-repeat="resource in resource_list | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:searchTable">`

I see ng-repeat used if the data is coming from js, but what do I use if I only want to sort and search?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I don't see resources in your scope, here is an example which I created for you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="currencyApp" ng-controller="currencyCtrl">

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in resources | orderBy:'country' | filter: 'a' ">
    {{ x.country + ', ' + x.currency }}
  </li>
</ul>

</div>

<script>
angular.module('currencyApp', []).controller('currencyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.resources = [
        {currency:'a',country:'Norway'},
        {currency:'b',country:'Sweden'},
        {currency:'c',country:'England'},
        {currency:'d',country:'Norway'},
        {currency:'e',country:'Denmark'},
        {currency:'g',country:'Sweden'},
        {currency:'h',country:'Denmark'},
        {currency:'i',country:'England'},
        {currency:'j',country:'Norway'}
        ];
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have not added a text field to filter, instead I have hard coded, to show you an working example

BTW, for sort to work, here is the syntax

```
{{ array-you-are-looping | orderBy : expression : true/false }}
```

if you set the third parameter to true like

```
 {{ array-you-are-looping | orderBy : expression : true}}
```

it sorts in reverse order

if you set the third parameter to false like

```
{{ array-you-are-looping | orderBy : expression : false }}
```

it sort in ascending order

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the issue i'm facing is my data is coming from my SQL DB with the for loop, not set in the script, so how can sort and filter data coming from this source ?

Answer (score 0):

**Remove** for loop, you don't want that when you use ng-repeat.

Then check bit about spelling. This must work. Did you check console.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The issues with that is the for loop brings in the data from my SQL DB. is there something else i can use other then ng-repeat to sort and filter my data